# What should we include in the page on civicrm.org that links here?

Tags: discussion

I just created a page on civicrm.org https://civicrm.org/ask-a-question. Do you have any suggested edits?

My thoughts are that we should keep the intro. i.e. the text before the 'Ask a question' link short, but then continue with advice, etc. on how to ask a question.

We should also add information that makes the site welcoming to new people.

Answer (score 3):

I recently updated the [Community Support Documentation](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Community+Support+Documentation) with a link to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/tour.  I'd include gentle language recommending this - "To get the best answers, take the two-minute [tour](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/tour), which will help you ask questions in a way that will get the best answers."

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure: is this the place for "Want to find out if CiviCRM is right for you?" questions? I imagine a lot of questions like, "I have a medium-sized nonprofit with events and donations and a Drupal site--is CiviCRM right for me?"  Someone would say yes, and we'd all vote it up.

Or, they'd want something more than "yes", a whole site plan perhaps, and be really disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether linking straight to the Ask a Question page is the best approach. Wouldn't we prefer people to search/browse first and learn a little about how Stack Exchange works?

Speaking of searching, I've pointed out on the partners list that [civisearch](https://civicrm.org/civisearch) does not search [civicrm.stackexchange.com](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com). I like civisearch, I used to use it a lot and I think it's a useful place to direct users to - or would be, if it searched civicrm.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1):

One thing I'd like to see included on that page is a feed of recent questions, to give them a taste of what the site is like. Probably this would be simple to implement using this site's rss feed.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a feed on that page to FAQs that are asked and answered on the stack exchange site. Both the questions with the highest ranked number of answers and curated FAQs that we ask and answer on StackExchange.